# How can I identify if an opportunity was created from lead conversion?

Tags: opportunity, lead-conversion

I want to know if opportunity is created after lead conversion or not for the formula field. Is there any way where I can check if particular opportunity is created from lead conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is as follows:

- Create a field on Lead (type checkbox) `Is_Lead__c`, default true
- Create a field on Opportunity (type checkbox) `Is_Originated_From_Lead_Conversion__c`, default false
- Use Lead Mapping to map `Lead.Is_Lead__c` to `Opportunity.Is_Originated_From_Lead_Conversion__c`

for legacy leads/Oppos, you'll need to follow the suggestion from sfdcfox

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to map the lead.ID to a new field on the opp, this way you have the Lead ID ready for easy usage in flows for example without a search first. AND you have a check if it originated from a lead. That this is not in the default data model of SF is a fail, just like Salesforce is in an existential way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without customization/code. You'd create a Lead field on the Opportunity, then set up a Process/Flow/Trigger to populate the field from the Lead upon conversion. You can query existing Leads and use the Import Wizard/Data Loader/etc to load the previously converted Leads into their Opportunity records.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is in the Opportunity, go to Opportunity History related list.

If Converted, the first record will show "Created by lead convert" (see screenshot)

[image: Created by Lead Convert]

You can also create a standard report of report type = `Opportunity Field History` and add a filter like `Field / Event = "Created by lead convert"` to find all the Opportunities that is created by Lead Convert